# How To Relocate Hawaii and Alaska Near North America Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm in a situation that i need to include Hawaii and Alaska to googlemap but i Added a jquery that prevent the Map to be dragged outside the American Bounderies

Is that possible to move Hawaii and Alaska Near North America Premise?? Thanks

Here is the one that prevents the Map from Dragging Outside the map

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var minZoomLevel = 5;

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: minZoomLevel,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     // Bounds for North America
     var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(28.70, -127.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.90)
   );

     // Listen for the dragend event
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
         if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

         // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

         var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

         if (x < minX) x = minX;
         if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
         if (y < minY) y = minY;
         if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

         map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
     });

     // Limit the zoom level
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
         if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
     });

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a question?  I think you will need a custom map (custom tiles) that puts Hawaii and Alaska where you want them.

Comment: @geocodezip is it possible to move alaska and hawaii nearer from north america?

Comment: Enrique, what you want is generally known as "insets". The same question was asked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/mgB7J4EsKZA) in 2008 (Google maps v2 ?) and suggests that the solution is to "insert another map as a custom control". Unfortunately a link to a demo is broken.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thats what i'm planning :( Thanks

Comment: Try a Google search for "google maps insets". Some of the other results look promising.

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than one Map showing.The image shows main Map USA, and two small Maps with Alaska and Hawaii.
[image]

The following code produced it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize()
{
    var USA = new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50);
    var ALASKA = new google.maps.LatLng(64.0000, -150.0000);
    var HAWAII = new google.maps.LatLng(21.3114, -157.7964);

    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 4,
        center: USA,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var myOptions2 =
    {
        zoom: 3,
        center: ALASKA,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var myOptions3 =
    {
        zoom: 6,
        center: HAWAII ,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);
    var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_3"), myOptions3);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function()
    {
        zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        map2.setZoom(zoomLevel);
        map3.setZoom(zoomLevel);
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "drag", function()
    {
        centre = map.getCenter();
        map2.setCenter(centre);
        map3.setCenter(centre);
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="top: 5px; left: 30px; width:800px; height:600px; float: left"></div>
<div id="map_canvas_2" style="top: 5px; left: 75px; width:300px; height:300px"></div>
<div id="map_canvas_3" style="top: 15px; left: 75px; width:300px; height:300px"></div>
</body>
```